# cURL - Trust only a particular (CA-signed) certificate

Tags: php, curl, ssl

Using cURL in PHP, I want to make a connection to a specific website with SSL, trusting only that particular website's certificate.  I know how to trust the issuing CA, but I don't want to do that - I just want to trust the particular public key that the website is known to be using.

I tried pointing to a copy of the website's current certificate with `CURLOPT_CAINFO`, but cURL continues to give me the same errors that it gives with no certificate information (either "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain" or "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate").

Copying the CA's certificate from the certificate chain does not resolve those errors, but installing the actual root CA (indicated by "Subject Type=CA" in the "Basic Constraints" field, I'm guessing) does.

Is there any way I can either convince cURL to trust a non-CA certificate as though it were its own CA, or alternately, construct a root CA certificate from someone else's SSL certificate (that I don't have the private key for)?

(I intend to load this certificate via `CURLOPT_CAINFO` only when connecting to this particular website, so there's no danger of giving the certificate too much trust.)

Comment: they could legitimately change their public key, this looks like a bad idea

Comment: @Dagon - its a very good design. Its called [Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning), and its similar to SSH's `StrictHostKeyChecking`. We've found key continuity is a more desirable attribute than any benefits from key rotation due to key management policies. You can also pin certificates, but that can get you in UI trouble. Organizations like Google rotate their certs every 15 or 30 days (to keep the CRL small for mobile clients), but they re-certify the same public key. That's the reason Cert Patrol is so noisy and misses the mark.

Comment: cURL does *not* have public key pinning (I grepped the source code looking for it in the past). There may be certificate pinning, but I can't follow some of the documents due to broken links. See [Feature Request 64 / Pinning SSL certificates / check SSL fingerprints](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/feature-requests/64/).

Comment: @jww That would qualify as an answer, I think, but for the sake of helping with my actual problem - would it work to create my own CA and sign the website's certificate with that?

Comment: @jww I was able to follow that broken link on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130427024551/http://sourceforge.net/p/whonix/wiki/Dev_sslcertpinning/) - but it seems to consist of connecting to the host without sensitive information and checking fingerprints manually before sending the real connection.